# Can Java compiler optimisation cause Google Guava's Preconditions checks to be ignored?

Tags: java, guava, compiler-optimization, remote-debugging, preconditions

We have a POJO in our Java application let's say `Request` which has validateRequest() method that basically validates some of it's fields using Guava's Preconditions library.

So, Basically Class looks like this :

```
public class Request { 
   private Integer field1; 
   
   private String field2;
   .
   .
   private String fieldN;

   
   public String validateRequest() {
      try { 
           Preconditions.checkArgument( getField1() >= 0, "error message" );

           Preconditions.checkArgument( StringUtils.isNotBlank(getField2()), "error message" );
           .
           .
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e){
            //emit some metric
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
   }
}
```

We call the below method in all the flows after building the Request POJO.

```
public void someMethod(Request request) {
    String message = request.validateRequest();
    if(message!= null)
       throw new Exception(message);
}
```

In some of the flows in our application we are never initialising field1 and field2 , so they are always null in those flows. So, ideal expectation is that validateRequest should return error message for those flows. But, what we notice is production is that this application never returns error message. It is as if Preconditions are never executed! Even metric that we emit is zero. On searching web, found out that compiler's optimisation can cause certain validation/assertion statements to be ignored, but didn't get more details around it.

When we explicitly remote debug to our Production box and put break-point on precondition statements they get executed and error message is returned and metric is emitted.

When we deploy this same application is deployed on Stage, code behaves as expected and throws validation error and metric is emitted.

Want to understand if compiler optimisation is the culprit here, or if root cause could be something else. How to verify that compiler optimisation is causing Preconditions to be ignored?

Comment: Is that method even called at all?

Comment: Yes we call it in all flows. That's why it gets hit during remote debug.

Comment: Let me rephrase : is that method called when you want it to be called? It could be called at some point, but not in every scenario you're testing. Just because it's a hit when you remote debug it means that it's exactly when you want it.

Comment: Yes, we call it in all possible flows. What's expected is validation should fail for some flows.

Comment: Then the answer is that it CANNOT be optimized away.  Your problem is caused by something else.  For example, some of your other assumptions are incorrect.   It is worth noting that debugging a program can cause various behavior related to memory visibility and concurrency to change.  So that's another implicit assumption that could be incorrect.

Comment: Your analysis has a few assumptions — like that this method gets called, that the getters return null, and that the catch isn't being triggered — that a couple log lines could very quickly validate. If you haven't done that yet, it's where I might start. (Just as a guess: you haven't shown the getters, so could it be they're providing a default? And you haven't shown the object's instantiation, so could it be that process is setting defaults?)

Comment: -> I am sure catch isn't triggered because Metric isn't emitted; same metric gets emitted when in remote debug exception is triggered. 
-> Have noticed fields are null and not default during remote debugging as well.

Comment: @StephenC let’s not call this an optimization, but *expected, reproducible behavior*. The strange thing here is that the OP says that the actual problem has not been revealed during debugging.

Comment: @Holger - it was the OP that is asking if this is the result of "optimization" ... not me.

Comment: @StephenC I know. It’s an interesting case of a questioner’s preoccupation influencing the readers. I think, without it, more people would have noticed that the OP’s “*It is as if Preconditions are never executed*” is actually spot on.

Comment: Or ... we were just answering the question that he asked :-)

Comment: @StephenC yes, the good old *xy problem*. Though, in the OP’s defense, this question has enough context to get to the actual problem. It only took a bit longer…

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to be a kind of Cargo Cult Programming. It’s not clear what you expect from the call to `Preconditions.checkArgument(…)`, but whatever it is, it’s not there.

When you call

```java
Preconditions.checkArgument( getField1() >= 0, "error message" );
```

The expression `getField1() >= 0` is evaluated *in your method*. You’ve already done the check before even calling the `checkArgument` method. All, the method does, is throwing a new `IllegalArgumentException` if the argument is `false`, with the message you’ve provided, i.e.

```java
public static void checkArgument(boolean expression, Object errorMessage) {
    if(!expression) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(errorMessage));
    }
}
```

which you then catch, to extract the very error message, you have provided yourself.

```java
catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e){
    //emit some metric
    return e.getMessage();
}
```

So, you have created an inefficient way to do the same as

```java
if(getField1() < 0) return "error message";
```

---

Since the evaluation of `getField1() >= 0` happens in your method, *before* the `checkArgument` method is invoked, it will also fail with a `NullPointerException` instead of ever invoking the `checkArgument` method when `getField1()` returned `null`. This JVM generated `NullPointerException` will have an implementation specific message or no message at all.

This is not an optimization but just the way method invocations work. First, the arguments are evaluated, then, the method is invoked. If the argument evaluation throws an exception the method is not invoked.

It’s not clear how you could see this working with a `getField1()` returning `null` during debugging, as it is impossible to pass `null` to a method expecting a primitive type `boolean`. Maybe you are confusing it with the scenario of `getField2()` returning `null`.

Your second check uses the expression `StringUtils.isNotBlank(getField2())` which handles the `null` case, as `isNotBlank` will return `false` when the argument is `null`.

You can fix the first check by handling the `null` case, e.g.

```java
if(getField1() == null || getField1() < 0) return "error message";
```

or, if you insist on creating and catching an exception, just to extract the very message you have specified yourself,

```java
Preconditions.checkArgument(getField1()!=null && getField1()>=0, "error message");
```